# How to slide questions in Surveyjs automatically without pressing Continue button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, surveyjs

I am using SurveyJs in my web app. My first 3 pages contain HTML which I wanted to slide after some seconds like in the below sample site using SurveyJS:
https://www.vivewellness.com/consultation/

In the above site, after you enter the name, 3-4 pages slide without pressing continue button and I want to reproduce this in my site.

I am using:
browser: Chrome,
browser version: Version 74.0.3729.131,
surveyjs platform : jQuery,
surveyjs version: 1.0.84

At first I tried setting "maxTimeToFinish": "2.2" in JSON, but it didn't worked out for me.

Can someone help me out reproducing the same effect as in the sample site?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `goNextPageAutomatic` option:

```js
{
  goNextPageAutomatic: true,
  ...
}
```

Please see the [doc](https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library/?id=surveymodel#goNextPageAutomatic)